# Imagick saving from browser as a php file

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have a php/imagick script that outputs a png image but when I go to save it from the browser it saves as the file name: `index.php` I want it to save as a png when you click save as image in your browser.

link: http://www.halogamertags.com/signatures/index.php?player=yoinked%20ya

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.png"');
```